# How to check multiple condition check visual studio 2008 Unit Testing framework

Tags: .net, unit-testing, c#-3.0, nunit, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am working on creating unit test cases for few methods. I want to verify the return value and the out parameter for certain condition. If the conditions are met then perticular case will success else fail.

How to do this in Unit Testing Framework Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks,
Omkar

Answer (score 2):

Inside your unit test method, create an assertion for each test.
For instance:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(returnValue);
Assert.IsTrue(anOutParameter > 0);
```

The test will only succeed if all the assertions succeed

Answer (score 2):

I've no experience with Unit Testing Framework Visual Studio 2008 but with other Unit Testing frameworks, in order to perform multiple checks you simply Assert multiple times.

For example:

```
// Arrange
bool isValid;

// Act
string output = MyClass.SomeMethod(out isValid);

// Assert    
Assert.IsTrue(isValid);
Assert.Equals("test", output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing away with the out parameter.. Check if you need both return values. Especially if your return value is an error codes. Use exceptions over error code as it simplifies client code

```
string realReturnValue;
if(!MyMethod(out realReturnValue)
{
  //handle error
}
```

vs

```
var realReturnValue = MyMethod()
```

If you must have them, create a type that wraps [Result, OutputValue]. Define Equals on this type.

`Assert.AreEqual(new ReturnType(true, "10"), valueReturnedByMethodCall)`